# EF5 Database first model templates (tt) for class generation

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-5, n-layer

I want to make that all my Entities created form an existing database inherits from the same interface.

I suppose this can be done through the templates. And I've seen that ugly `.tt` file, but there is no help (or I haven't found it).

There are any documentation, examples, ... of the templates?

There are any tips or pre-made templates for common paradigms, for example N-Layer Design or Domain Driven Desing?

Comment: Database first and DDD ?  Please explain that concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for "T4 Templates". That will give you introduction to T4 Templates (`.tt` files).
With a bit of searching you can easily extend this template to your needings. I did this myself already, but with a template from EF4. I don't know if the templates differ.

I made a little helper functions for this:

```
string Interfaces(EntityType entity)
{
    string interfaces = string.Empty;

    if (entity.Members.OfType<EdmProperty>().Any(edmProperty => edmProperty.Name == "Guid" && ((PrimitiveType)edmProperty.TypeUsage.EdmType).PrimitiveTypeKind == PrimitiveTypeKind.Guid))
    {
        interfaces += ", IHasWritableGuid";
    }

    return interfaces;
}
```

The part where the template writes the actually entity class (this differs for sure in the new template) is somewhat below "`Write EntityType classes.`" in the EF4 template.

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#>
<#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>
partial class
<#=code.Escape(entity)#> :
<#=BaseTypeName(entity, code)#>
<#= Interfaces(entity) #>
```

Here I just added a call to my interfaces method.

I know this is not the exact answer, but it should give you help with editing the template file yourself. Just bite yourself through it. :)

Comment: Ok thanks, and if I update my model from the database it will automatically apply the new template?

Comment: The template will be executed whenever you save your .edmx file, so yeah: It will be updated when you update your model.